# Triggered Send to two subscriberIDs on same data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, triggered-send

We have created a referral program in ExactTarget that has a triggered send email sent to the referred person. when they sign-up to the mailing list we want to send another email to the original referrer.

We have created one data extension that has the SubscriberID of the referred people as the key subscriber relationship. On the same row as the referred person is the original referrers SubscriberID.

Is it possible to send the original referrer an email using this same data extension or do I need to create a separate data extension to send to these people?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subscriber will need to be in the data extension in a field with a relationship to Subscriber ID, of which there is only one per data extension. If you wanted to use the same data extension, you could add an additional field that denotes whether the subscriber is a referral or the referrer to keep track. It would probably make more sense to just use two different data extensions though to avoid the problem of a person who both refers someone and has been referred by someone else.